# How to achieve one row with two column and second row with single column using TableLayout

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, toolbar

I want first row having two columns and second row with single column. I will try to add column but it is not getting added for first row. Column is added for two rows. How to solve this issue? I need to hide first row and fist column also when certain flag is set.

Comment: Do you mean on a datagrid? Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: No I want to place toolbar on first row and first column in WinForms.Button on first row and second column and Teechart on second row which has single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

**First: `ColumnSpan`**

1. Create a `TableLayoutPanel` with 2 rows and 2 columns.
2. In cell (0,0) you put your toolbar (I'll use a `ToolStrip`).
3. In cell (0,1) you put your `Button` (although I don't understand why not add a extra button to the toolbar).
4. In cell (1,0) you put the chart and.
5. Now you set the chart's `ColumnSpan` property to 2, which will cause it to stretch over both bottom columns.

**Second: Nested `TableLayoutPanel` Instances**

1. Create a `TableLayoutPanel` (TP1) with 2 rows and 1 column.
2. Add another `TableLayoutPanel` (TP2) to the top row of TP1, with 1 row and 2 columns.
3. Put your toolbar in the left column of the TP2.
4. Put your `Button` in TP2's right column.
5. Put the chart in TP1's bottom row.
6. You may set TP2's left column's size-type to AutoSize. This way - when you'll set the toolbar's `Visible` property to `false`, TP2's left column will disappear and the right column will now stretch over the whole top row.

I think solution 2 will better fit your needs because it'll be easier to hide TP2's left column.